# spss python string occurrences in a variable

Tags: python, spss

How to count number of occurrences in string using spss python.I am trying to count the number of "i" in a particular entire variable columns. I am new to spss python. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: What did you try so far? How does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need python for this task, just work with regular SPSS syntax.

Paste the following in a syntax window, and change "MyString" into the name of your string variable:

EDIT: changed to dinamic sized loop:

```
compute Nletters=length(rtrim(MyString)).
compute MyCount=0.
loop #n=1 to Nletters.
if char.substr(MyString,#n,1)="i" MyCount=MyCount+1.
end loop.
exe.
```

This will create a new variable that will contain the number of "i"s in the string in each line.

You can now sum that up for the whole column using the `aggregate` command or the following command to get the sum in the output window:

```
means  MyCount /cells=sum.
```

Comment: Instead of doing a fixed loop, you can calculate the number of characters in the string and then loop based on that variable. That takes away the magic 100 (or whatever) length you have to put in.